# threading in Windows store app

Tags: multithreading, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, c++-cx

I am reading sample Hilo provided by MS, under ImageBrowserViewModel.cpp there is some code I am not understand:

```
// Observe the update after waiting the specified amount of time.
create_task([timeToWait]() {
    assert(IsBackgroundThread());
    ::wait(timeToWait);
}).then([weakThis]() {
    assert(IsMainThread());
    auto vm = weakThis.Resolve<ImageBrowserViewModel>();
    if (nullptr != vm)
    {
        vm->ObserveFileChange();
        vm->m_hasFileUpdateTask = false;
    }
}, task_continuation_context::use_current()).then(ObserveException<void>(m_exceptionPolicy));
```

The quest is app use `IsBackgroundThread()` & `IsMainThread()` to assert it should be correctly called under certain context. But for the `::wait(timeToWait)` function call, there is no `task_continuation_context` defined to make sure it runs in background, I just wonder how does it make to work?? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The default for constructed tasks (as the first task is in your code snippet) is `task_continuation_context::use_arbitrary()`, so even though it is not specified this is what it will be.  The task continuation lambda does assert this before calling ::wait (which would throw an exception if it attempted to run on the UI thread).